# how to simulate the inheritance of a record?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, record

I'd like to inherit records, since this is not possible the best solution is to create classes with public fields and use inheritance against them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, uses classes. There is a complete discussion in the [Stack Overflow question *Why can't Delphi records have inheritance?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095596/why-cant-delphi-records-have-inheritance)

Comment: If you create LOTS of objects than class is slower than record.

Comment: One solution to the overhead of extra objects is to use a flyweight design pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern